# Não deixar usuário fechar aplicação / ou realizar uma ação antes de fechar

Tags: android

Pessoal na minha aplicação o usuário faz um pedido, esse pedido ganha um Status de novo, quero que quando ele feche a aplicação em quanto está realizando o pedido, o status seja alterado para cancelado e seja enviado para o servidor.
Tentei implementar isso no onDestroy mas não funcionou.

Quando falo fechar a aplicação é quando ele exibe todas aplicações abertas e arrasta pro lado a aplicação, aí ele acaba fechando.

Ou se possível até não deixar ele encerrar a aplicação.

Comment: O conceito de "fechar", nos termos em que você se refere, não existe no Android. O metodo onDestroy raramente(quase que diria nunca) é chamado.

Comment: E quando o usuário exibe todos apps em execução, e arrasta o app para algum lado ele some dos apps em execução. Meus serviços param.

Comment: Como é que está a fazer o *start* dos serviços?

Comment: Pelo que entendi quando um usuario está cadastrando um pedido, o servidor mantem o status de aberto, e ele espera o usuario confirmar ou cancelar o pedido para alterar o status. Se for isso, acho que o servidor não precisa saber se o usuario está efetuando um pedido, o servidor deve apenas se preocupar se o usuario realmente confirmar o pedido.

Comment: Bem eu preciso cadastrar esse pedido, porque eu tenho outro app da versão prestador de serviço, que atende esse pedido.

Comment: Os dois meio que se comunicam no mesmo tempo.